# Rails delete_if only working if I print to the logger after I push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
#   
teams_attributes = Array.new(3) {Hash.new}
teams_attributes[0][:players_attributes] = Array.new()
teams_attributes[1][:players_attributes] = Array.new()
teams_attributes[2][:players_attributes] = Array.new()

teams_attributes[player[:state].to_i][:players_attributes].push({:user_id=>player[:user_id].to_i, :score=>player[:score]})

#... 
temp = teams_attributes.to_s # Makes absolutely no sense why I had to add this line of code, but it makes the below line of code work and not get an undefined error.
teams_attributes.delete_if {|x| x[:players_attributes].blank?}
# ...
```

I've spent hours debugging this and discovered that my delete_if statement only works if I run a line of code that includes something like teams_attributes.to_s or similar (I discovered because logger.debug(teams_attributes.to_s) also works.

Any idea why in the world the delete_if command needs a "break" before executing to work successfully? If I comment out the # temp = ... I get a 
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass) error

Also worth noting that if I convert the delete_if to a block and print out to the console each element (x), it is always blank unless I include that weird line of code temp = teams_attributes.to_s

Comment: Are `team_attributes` AR objects?  If so, they may not be loaded at the time of running `delete_if`... Just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately it is not. It is setup earlyier in the method call (just edited my question above).

Comment: Ok, if I try this in the rails console this just works. So maybe you have to look further. On which line do you get the `NoMethodError`? And how do you print to the console each element? The `to_s` has no effect on `teams_attributes` soooo ... :)

Comment: What's the player object?  Can you provide some details on its class and behavior?

Comment: The player object is just an array of data that I submitted to my rails API. I pull it right out of the params[:players] and loop through it:
          players = params[:players]

          players.each do |player|

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
teams_attributes.to_a.delete_if {|x| x[:players_attributes].blank?}
```

The teams_attributes is presumably a ActiveRecord relation, which is lazily loaded.  `delete_if` is a method on Array, but not on Enumerable, so the relation doesn't load the array when `delete_if` is called.

You should also be able to use `reject!`, which is on Enumerable, like so:

```
teams_attributes.reject! {|x| x[:players_attributes].blank?}
```

Comment: How about `team_attributes.all.delete_if {|x| x[:players_attributes].blank?}`?

Comment: Thanks again, but that didn't work either. The strangest thing is that if I actually loop through the array using a block for delete_if and print it out it is totally blank... but if I have that one line of code inserted (temp = teams_attributes.to_s) before I loop through it it is not blank.

Comment: What's crazy is I just try adding sleep 1.5 instead of temp = teams_attributes.to_s and it works with sleep as well. Almost like the array needs a little delay to actually populate before I start deleting stuff out of it. Very strange.